# Python: How to change the format of Sep 07 2014 (string) to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: python, datetime, formatting

I have date as a string in this format : Sep 07 2014 
and I am willing to change it to this format dd/mm/yyyy

currently I am using this code by I recive the following error:

```
for l in line:
    l = l.strip('\n').replace('"','')
    bl_time = l.split('\t')
    print bl_time
    s = datetime.datetime.strptime(bl_time,"%b %d %Y")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/scripts/whois.py", line 25, in <module>
    s = datetime.datetime.strptime(bl_time,"%b %d %Y")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'bl_date' does not match format '%b %d %Y'


bl_time is :
May 03 2014
Sep 05 2014


and  print '"{}"'.format(bl_time) is :
"May 03 2014"
"Sep 05 2014"
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Much better post edit +1. What is the value of `bl_time`?

Comment: And this is why you should write a good question the first time, instead of editing a heavily-downvoted question into a better one

Comment: Change `print bl_time` to `print '"{}"'.format(bl_time)` to see if there's any extra whitespace in bl_time...

Comment: @TomDalton  this is the print results:                                   "Sep 07 2014"
"Jun 08 2012"
"Sep 07 2014"
"Jul 24 2014"

Comment: I think this is happening with one particular input only and not all inputs. To resolve this, I would put this within  a try-except block and figure out the offending input..

Comment: OK I'm confused - in the question you said bl_time was "May 03 2014" "Sep 05 2014". I assumed you mean that "Sep 05 2014" is the value that causes the exception. Now you say it's "Sep 07 2014", "Jun 08 2012", "Sep 07 2014", "Jul 24 2014". Is it the last string that causes the exception? Could you create a minimal example that reproduces the problem that we can all try for ourselves?

Comment: Hang on. `bl_time = l.split('\t')`. Doesn't that mean bl_time is a list?!

Comment: @TomDalton Just as an example. I am printing a table , these are all examples.

Comment: @mu無 good idea, let me try

Comment: you need to give us your actual code. Ideally a minimal example that I can run myself. Otherwise it's very difficult to help you - the code you are showing us isn't your real code, and the problem is almost certainly in something you haven't shown us.

Comment: @TomDalton Sure sorry. I found the problem was in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Ref:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

You can do this:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("Sep 07 2014", "%b %d %Y")
print d
print d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks! Check my edition! my issue is something else

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dt  = datetime.datetime.strptime("Sep 07 2014", "%b %d %Y")
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 7, 0, 0)
>>> dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'07/09/2014'
```

---

This is converting your text string into a datetime object (utilizing [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)) and then formatting that based on your required format using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

Comment: A small note - he wanted dd/mm/yyyy, not mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @Andy Thanks. Check my error! my problem is that it says that this is not the correct format

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the excellent [python-dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.2) library:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

try:
    parse(bl_time).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
except:
    print "could not parse %s" % bl_time
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents/scripts/whois.py", line 27, in <module>
    s= parse(bl_time).strftime('%M/%D/%Y')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py", line 697, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py", line 303, in parse
    raise ValueError, "unknown string format"
ValueError: unknown string format

Comment: all the date strings listed are working for me.  maybe the edited try/except version will give us a clue?